# dynamic field in interface - how to work around it?

Tags: c#

I have the following interface which defines `dynamic AcceptableValue {get; set;}`.

I know that the interface should always have something that's concrete, not `dynamic` or `object`, but I'm struggling a bit on how to get this done without defining `dynamic AcceptableValue`.

I guess I could take the field AcceptableValue out of the interface and declare it on each class with the proper type, but I think there has to be a better way of doing...

```
    interface IPrerequisite
    {
            string Name { get; set; }

            dynamic AcceptableValue { get; set; }

            string FailureText { get; set; }

            string SuccessText { get; set; }

            bool Validate();
    }

    public class Ram : IPrerequisite
    {
            public Ram(string name = "RAM Requirements", string value = "2048", string successText = "Minimum {0}MB RAM required", string failureText = "Minimum {0}MB RAM required")
            {
                    Name = name;
                    AcceptableValue = value;
                    SuccessText = successText;
                    FailureText = failureText;
            }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public dynamic AcceptableValue { get; set; }

            public string SuccessText { get; set; }

            public string FailureText { get; set; }

            public bool Validate()
            {
                    var ram = GetRam();
                    return  ram >= AcceptableValue;
            }
    }

    public class DeviceModel : IPrerequisite
    {
            public class Device
            {
                    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

                    public string Model { get; set; }
            }

            private IList<Device> _value;

            public DeviceModel(string name = "Computer Model Support", IList<Device> value = null, string successText = "Computer Model '{0}' Supported", string failureText = "Computer Model '{0}' not Supported")
            {
                    Name = name;
                    _value = value;
                    SuccessText = successText;
                    FailureText = failureText;
            }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public dynamic AcceptableValue
            {
                    get { return _value; }
                    set { _value = value; }
            }

            public IList<Device> GetSupportedModels()
            {
                    return _value;
            }

            public void AddSupportedModel(string manufacturer, string model)
            {
                    if (_value.Any(aDevice => aDevice.Manufacturer == manufacturer && aDevice.Model == model))
                    {
                            return;
                    }

                    var device = new Device {Manufacturer = manufacturer, Model = model};
                    _value.Add(device);
            }

            public void RemoveSupportedModel(string manufacturer, string model)
            {
                    var supportedModel = _value.First(device => device.Manufacturer == manufacturer && device.Model == model);

                    _value.Remove(supportedModel);
            }

            private bool IsModelSupported(string manufacturer, string model)
            {
                    return _value.Any(device => device.Manufacturer == manufacturer && device.Model == model);
            }

            public string SuccessText { get; set; }

            public string FailureText { get; set; }

            public bool Validate()
            {

                    return IsModelSupported(GetComputerManufacturer(), GetComputerModel());
            }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considerd making the interface a generic type (IPrerequisite<T> with AcceptableValue of type T)?

Comment: Was trying to wait a bit longer to see if other suggestions came through, but it doesn't look like they will. You suggestion works well and is definitely an improvement over the `dynamic` so I'll go with that.